# e4 custom savehandler dialog for a part

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, rcp, e4

In my e4 application I've got multiple parts, all of which contain a MDirtyable. Now there is a specific one for which I'd like to show a custom dialog when prompting the user for saving.
I was trying to set a custom handler in the MWindow context but that will change the behavior for all active parts, not just the one i'm interested in. Is there any way I can achieve this ? I'm thinking something about getting the context for a part only, and change the handler in it, but I don't know if that's possible. Thanks in advance.

Update: Thanks for your answers. So far I tried changing back to default handler after the custom part is being saved. Here's some code:

```
//custom part
@PostConstruct
public void createComposite(Composite parent, MWindow window) {

    this.windowContext = window.getContext(); //get current context
    this.old = windowContext.get(ISaveHandler.class); //save current handler
    windowContext.set(ISaveHandler.class, new CustomSaveHandler()); //set a custom handler
}
```

and when the saving is done change back to default handler

```
@Persist
public void save() {
    dirty.setDirty(false);
    windowContext.set(ISaveHandler.class, old); //switch to old handler
}
```

So this works fine when I open a custom part, make some changes to it and then close. But if there are multiple parts opened, they will all inherit the custom handler untill I close the custom part.
Any other ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

No, the save handler is looked up in the `MWindow` context so you can't set it for just a single part.

You would have to reproduce the standard behavior in the save handler for the other parts.

Comment: so if I understand correctly there can be only one savehandler active at a time, for all the parts. is there a way I can switch back to the default handler within the custom part, after the saving is done ?

Comment: You could try setting the ISaveHandler.class entry in the MWindow IEclipseContext to null.